# List items behave strange when containing no text

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, font-awesome, limesurvey

Recently I made an attempt to transfer a Zurb Foundation template/site I built into a LimeSurvey template and in the process I noticed that my Font-Awesome links were not displaying correctly any more...

It should be displaying like:
[image: correct font awesome display]

However instead it displays like:
[[image: incorrect font awesome display[2]]

It is resolved when I enter text like so:
[image: partial font awesome fix]

But that's not what I want to do, I need it empty.

It was all working fine when just running the site on local Apache.

Anyone got any pointers?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Instead of empty `<li>`, try using a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`.

Comment: try adding `line-height: 100%` to your fa icons